# Summarize by group like proc sql

Tags: r

I have a SKU -week data which has different in-store activities (Tactics). I want to summarize each variables by the tactics. Pasting the code in SAS:

```
proc sql; 
create table lp.lp_sku_report1 
as select distinct(tactic), sum(Sales_Stat_Case_10_Lt) as Sales_Stat_Case_10_Lt, sum(Sales_Units) as Sales_Units, sum(Sales_Dollars) as Sales_Dollars,  sum(Baseline_Stat_Case_10_Lt) as Baseline_Stat_Case_10_Lt, sum(Baseline_Units) as Baseline_Units, sum(Baseline_Dollars) as Baseline_Dollars
from lp.lp_sku_data 
group by tactic; quit;
```

Comment: How about showing a small reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

with `dplyr` package it's very easy to perform this action. first group by the variable tactic and then `summarise` rest of the variables by using the aggregating function `sum`.

In this specific case since the aggregating function is same for all the variables you can use `summarise_each` to apply the same function to all variables.

below is the code

```
library(dplyr)

    df = df %>%
      group_by(tactic) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Comment: Better add some explanatory text or it will be flagged for possible deletion as "too short". SO is looking for quality...